# Having problems deploying an go app to docker

Tags: go, docker

Hi I am pretty new to go, and this is my first time working with docker to package an app into a container. I am working on a linux VM where the app is located under dir: /home/core/app/app-name In the dir app-name there is the main.go program and the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile contains this:

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /home/core/app/app-name
WORKDIR /app/app-name
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I have tried running from dir /home/core/app/app-name:

```
docker build -t app-image .
```

But I got this error:

can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /app/stars-app
The command '/bin/sh -c go build -o main .' returned a non-zero code: 1

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I got was able to build the image on my windows machine with the Dockfile:

```
FROM golang:latest
Add . /app/app-name
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app/app-name/main"]
```

And by running:

```
docker build -t star-image .
```

I can see the image when I run "docker images", but when I try to run it using:

```
docker run -p 3000:8080 --name goapp --rm app-name
```

I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/app/app-name/main' not found or does not exist..
```

Comment: You're adding everything to `/home/core/app/app-name`, but your WORKDIR is `/app/app-name`. You also don't set GOPATH, and don't specify an package to build. If you're building the app in the container, you still need to have a proper environment setup as described in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: i think you put the files in `/home/core/app/app-name` instead of `/app/app-name`. try making the dirs consistent, maybe `RUN go build -o main /app/app-name` and `CMD ["/app/app-name/main"]`

Comment: @Plato, I have tried that but I still got the same output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you...

- The GOPATH for the image is set to /go
- install your source(s) under /go/src
- given the gopath is set and sources are within the GOPATH
- setting the working directory to /app
- execute the build and the output should be present in the working
  directory

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:latest
ADD ./app /go/src/app
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main app/app-name
CMD ["/app/main"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

---

**app/app-name/main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

---

```
docker build -t app-image .
docker run app-image
```

---

**output**

```
hello, world
```

Comment: When I ran it I got:
Sending build context to Docker daemon 100.9 kB
Step 1 : FROM golang:latest
 ---> 5850add7ecc2
Step 2 : ADD ./app /go/src/app
lstat app: no such file or directory

Comment: @ChristopherStephenson locally in the directory where the Dockerfile is located I have a folder named "app" containing a subfolder named "app-name" containing a single file "main.go" ..was trying to mimick your app structure based on the information provided. [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62bd07425ac0dc62304a28501dc4c456)

Comment: @gist, I was able to get it working, and build the image, but I am still having problems running it. See my edit for the updated info

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this too but somehow based on this [guide](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang), this worked for me.

```
# ...AS builder ...

FROM golang:1.14
WORKDIR /go/src/app
# In your case, ./main.go or just .
COPY ./server.go .
COPY --from=builder ./app/build .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]
```